# If result = 0/null then change where?

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
select
C.[Exchange Rate Amount]

from [Canada].[vCurrencyRate] as C

Where
C.[Currency Code] = 'CAD'
AND cast(C.Date as date) = cast( getdate() as date)
```

What I would like it to do is if the result is 0, then roll back the date one day

```
Where
C.[Currency Code] = 'CAD'
AND IF C.[Exchange Rate Amount] = 0 then cast(C.Date as date) = datediff( day, -1, cast( getdate() as date)) else cast(C.Date as date) = cast( getdate() as date)
```

However I can't figure out how to make it work

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query uses some product specific functions.)

Comment: Do you have one table per country (e.g. Canada)? Seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row, use `order by` and limit to one row:

```
select top (1) C.[Exchange Rate Amount]
from [Canada].[vCurrencyRate] as C
Where C.[Currency Code] = 'CAD' AND cast(C.Date as date) <= cast( getdate() as date)
order by c.date DESC;
```

Because of the square braces and `getdate()`, I'm assuming this is SQL Server.  Other databases would use `limit` or `fetch first 1 row only`.